# Is the RestKit seed database refreshed on every app install, or just on the first install?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, core-data, restkit

I have an app that's had a major refresh, and we're about to release v2.0. I can't seem to find info anywhere in the RestKit docs (or in any articles/tutorials) that mentions **when** the seed database is used.

I understand that when you first install an app with a RestKit seed database, the data is inserted. However if you have v1 installed and install v2 over it, does the database get re-seeded or is it just left the same as it was?

Our issue is that we're sending an If-Modified-Since header, but we want it to be as recent as possible - ideally since the last db seed, a few weeks before that release. If we release v2 with a July 2015 If-Modified-Since, does this mean that those with v1 and an old database will miss updates that happened before July 2015, since they'll have missed out on the seed database and thus be forever outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes here later, I can confirm that the seed database is only used on first install.

In retrospect this makes sense; if it was re-generated every update, customers would lose all their data. Our data is almost entirely read-only, so I didn't even consider it.